# Modificar valor al tener un NameError mediante try exception

Tags: python, excepciones

Al intentar convertir un string a diccionario me salta un error de tipo `NameError` porque este contiene valores `true` y `false` con la primera letra en minúscula.

Se que puedo emplear `try exception` para trabajar errores pero no se cómo hacer para modificar las variables. ¿Como hago en este caso para que ponga en mayúscula la primera de los booleanos?

```
try:
    dicc = eval(response.text)
except NameError:
    print('ERROR')
```

Donde `response.text`viene de una petición hecha con la librería `requests`.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Recomendación, evita usar `eval()`. Nunca de los nuncas, jamás de los jamases a menos que sepas lo que estás haciendo. Esa función convierte cadenas de texto en código Python, no querrás que alguien te pase `eval('os.system("RM -RF /")')` y quedarte sin sistema operativo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supongo que está obteniendo una respuesta en formato json, no un diccionario de Python. Es mejor usar el módulo apropiado en lugar de `eval`:

```
import json

dicc = json.loads(response.text)
```

Además, el response que devuelven las funciones del módulo `requests` tiene un método `json()` especial:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('some-url.com')
dicc = response.json()
```

Incluso te aconsejaría que nunca uses `eval`, incluso si realmente quieres.

[Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)